# some fields does not show using Display Suite

Tags: 7, display-suite

I build a content type and added fields as usual,after that I installed [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module to control on layout I built a content type and added fields as usual after that I installed display suite module to control on display layout.

I selected "Two column stacked" layout to my content type, then i enabled [print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module to allow the users to print the nodes of content type.

the important point is i added a views (block display) as a dynamic field to that content type which the views has a Contextual filters (node id) but the problem is when i want to print the node and press the print link the views does not show in the print page.

I think the problem causing by "Contextual filters" because the node url `http://localhost/demo/content-title/13` changed to `http://localhost/demo/print/13` .

how to make the views block showing when printing ?

Comment: Did you check user permission on those fields?